# Error al crear tabla en MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Quiero crear una tabla pedido en mysql, y me tira esto:

Executed SQL Statement :

```
Create table `deliverytrackingdb`.`pedido`(  
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `precio` double(5) NOT NULL,

  `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

  `direccion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

  `comentario` varchar(200),

  `estado` enum('En preparación','Preparado','Asignado a repartidor','En reparto','Entregado') NOT NULL,

  primary key (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

> Error Number : 1064 
>   Error Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,
>
> `descripcion` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
>    `direccion` varchar(200) ' at line 3

Comment: Recomiendo leer porque puede traer problemas usar tipo double http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html, recuerde que pudo haber especificado `precio double(5,2) NOT NULL` para especificar un número de 2 cifras decimales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quita el valor entre paréntesis del valor del double:

```
`precio` double NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score -1):

El tipo de dato `varchar` no se marca en *"azulito"*, puede que no sea la sintaxis adecuada, puedes utilizar `Char(n)`: Almacena una cadena de longitud fija. La cadena podrá contener desde 0 a 255 caracteres.